# Check if the ninth number from the right id 5 using Regex

Tags: php, regex

is it possible to check the ninth number from the right whether its 5 or not.

I want to check the 9<sup>th</sup> digit from the right is a five:

```
00966588696745
     ^-True
12088696748
  ^-False
```

is it possible ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Use `substr` with `$start` argument set to `-9` and `$length` set to `1`.

Comment: it's for checking whether the phone number is correct or not.

Comment: Did you try @WiktorStribiżew suggestion? https://eval.in/707778. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php `If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead: `5(?=\d{8}$)`

This will ensure that your test string contains a 5 followed by 8 digit and the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you  but, I want to to check this phone number 00966588696748, by counting from the right  9 steps to check whether the ninth number is 5 or not . like this I took last 9 numbers  "588696748"  and the first number is 5 than correct condition if not  it's not match.  Can I do that ?

Comment: @user3763103 it [works](https://ideone.com/tDsoVF)

Comment: Thank you it works as I want ^^

Answer (score 0):

A simple version of this would be as follows:

```
^5.{8}$
```

Explanation:
    **^** - start looking from beginning of the string 
    **5** - you want to ensure that the string starts with 5
    **.** - any character. But if you need to assure it is only digits you need to use \d instead (the \ is important)
    **{8}** - you expect for 8 chars of any type (since we use dot: '.')
    **$** - means end of the string. This assures that you have exactly 8 chars before end of the string


I hope this answer is helpful and explains the parts inside the regexpr